# Function pass by value with multiple string as parameter

Tags: c, c-strings

main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "function.h"
extern void CalcTax(float Gross, float Deffered, float *FedTax, float *StateTax, float *SSITax);
int main(void)
{
    float FedTax, StateTax, SSITax, hours, payrate, defr;
    char lastname, firstname;
    EmployeeData(&lastname, &firstname, &hours, &payrate, &defr);
    printf("%s\n", &lastname);
    printf("%s\n", &firstname);
    CalcTax(CalcGross(hours, payrate), defr, &FedTax, &StateTax, &SSITax);
    printf("Your Gross is: %f\n", CalcGross(hours, payrate));
    printf("the Federal Tax is %f\n",FedTax);
    printf("the State Tax is %f\n",StateTax);
    printf("the SSI Tax is %f\n",SSITax);
    return 0;
}
void EmployeeData(char *lastname, char *firstname, float *hours, float *payrate, float *defr)
{
    printf("last name?\n");
    scanf("%s", lastname);
    printf("first name?\n");
    scanf("%s", firstname);
    printf("hours?\n");
    scanf("%f",hours);
    printf("payrate?\n");
    scanf("%f",payrate);
    printf("defr?\n");
    scanf("%f",defr);
}
```

Can someone help me with this code I'm trying to get the lastname and firstname input and pass it to main as a string.  However, when I run the code above I only get random letters and only 1 or 2 letters at once not a full name.  I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4):

```
char lastname, firstname;
```

declares only single characters. You need arrays-of-char instead, if scanf shall be able to store more than a single character.

```
char lastname[42], firstname[42];  /* Assuming max length of names is 41 plus a NUL. */
```

Then call with

```
EmployeeData(lastname, firstname, &hours, &payrate, &defr);
```

Answer (score 3):

`char lastname, firstname;` declare lastname and firstname of type char.

You should use

```
char lastname[MAX_NAME_LENGTH + 1], firstname[MAX_NAME_LENGTH + 1]; /* +1 for \0 */
```

While calling the function, call it like:

```
EmployeeData(lastname, firstname, &hours, &payrate, &defr);
```

Answer (score 0):

you declared firstname and lastname as char and not an array of char so it holds only one char at a time.

Another important point:
The title of the Question is "pass by value". although you are calling the function in the following way:

```
EmployeeData(&lastname, &firstname, &hours, &payrate, &defr);
```

the & charachter actually sends the string by reference and not by value, so a change of the value in the function will be noticed outside the function as appose to sending by value in which changing the variable in the function won't affect the variable in the calling function.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using functions with no return value (void) if you actually want to return something?
I recommend using a string-array for your return value.

If you want to stick with your approach, keep in mind:
variables in `C` are only passed by value. In this case, when entering `EmployeeData(...)`, the compiler spawns a *copy* of your pointer variables, which point to a new place in memory.

You need to use pointer to pointer in order to change variables from main in your function, e.g.:
`EmployeeData(string** lastname,...)`

`*lastname = "yourstring"`